# Qt5 - how can I add sqlite database permanently in qt c++ application

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, qt, qt5

Currently, I am using SQLite database using this method:

```
QSqlDatabase Database; Database.addDatabase("QSQLITE");
Database.setDatabaseName("C:/Users/ARASH/Desktop/arash.db");
```

But, this isn't permanent. Because the application will not work for a different desktop folder under a different user. I want my application to run on other machines as well. So, I need a permanent solution for generalizing database path for every computer. Like: we can add pictures on resource.qrc. I want to use database in that way.

Comment: Didn't get it. Can you please elaborate or give some video or tutorial link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a DB path relative to your executable.

For example, you have a directory structure like this:

```
app folder
- executable
- data.db
```

So, it would be:

```
Database.setDatabaseName("data.db");
```

Alternatively, you can use [QStandardPaths](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html) class to get the `DesktopLocation` or other locations as per your requirements.